# Get variable between Segues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, tableview, viewcontroller

I am facing a situation that I dont know how to implement. My project is very simple where I have:

1. A ViewController that presents a webview with a specific URL;
2. On the same viewcontroller there is a button that goes to another viewController implemented by segue;
3. The second VC has a tableview already loaded, so when the user pick one cell, I get the value and return back to the main viewController (step.1);

So far it's implemented, then what I need to implement is when coming back to the main ViewController (step.1), I need to recover the value chosen at step.3, append the value to the URL and reload the WebView component.
How can I do that? I wonder that is simple but I couldn't find on my researches.

Thank you in advance any help, very welcome.
Alex

Comment: What type of segue are you using? push or modal?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. The trick is to able to access the variable(the value you want to pass) in the first view controller. One way to do this is explained in the answer. Another is to use the applications delegate or globally accessible object to store the variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are moving back from the tableview on click of a cell you could either implement it in `viewWillDisappear` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`(delegate method) of the tableview controller.

You can declare a variable with accessors in the first view controller (say returnedValue of type NSString)
then in the viewWillDisappear or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can pass the variable to the presentingViewController property.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController: UIViewController{
    NSString *returnedValue;
}
@property (strong) NSString *returnedValue;
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize returnedValue;
```

In **SecondViewController.m**:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  FirstViewController *firstVC = (FirstViewController *)[self presentingViewController];
  firstVC.returnedValue = @"The value you want to pass";
}
```

Then in your FirstViewController , in the appropriate method you can implement:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"%@",returnedValue"]; //according to your business logic
[yourWebView loadURL:url];
```

Comment: As I am beginner at objective-c, I understood what you meant, however I still have a question where or how I should declare this variable on the FirstViewController, such as @property NSString *selectedCategoryVC; ???
Even though, I cant see this property on the secondVC.

Comment: and one more question ... which method should I implement on the FirstViewController to receive the returnedValue and reload the Web View? Thank you a lot for helping.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can use any method as self.returnedValue is populated. For instance if you want to load the web view right when you get back to the view, then you can use `viewDidAppear:`. Or you could use the method you use to load the web view. Its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...worked through tons of tutorials and books. Here's what worked for me. It mixes two methods, and probably only one is needed. But at least I understand it and can use it easily. The methods are delegation and using a singleton to hold your global variable.

I pasted my code into Word, removed the stuff that didn't apply, and left everything you need, I think.

First, you make a new class file. Mine's called OptionsSingleton. This gives you OptionsSingleton.h and OptionsSingleton.m.
Mine has more variables in it, but here's what applies to you:

OptionsSingleton.h

```
@interface OptionsSingleton : NSObject{
int gblRowPicked;

}

@property(nonatomic) int gblRowPicked;

+(OptionsSingleton *) singleObj;

@end
```

OptionsSingleton.m

```
#import "OptionsSingleton.h"

@implementation OptionsSingleton
{
    OptionsSingleton * anotherSingle;
}
@synthesize gblRowPicked;

+(OptionsSingleton *)singleObj{

    static OptionsSingleton * single=nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!single)
        {
            single = [[OptionsSingleton alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return single;
}

@end
```

All the other viewcontrollers can see gblRowPicked, if you tell them about the existence of the singleton.

```
//  ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OptionsSingleton.h"

@interface ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController.h  : UIViewController 
{

    OptionsSingleton *optionsSingle;
}
```

and...

```
//  ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController.m

#import "ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController.h"
#import "OptionsSingleton.h"

@interface ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    optionsSingle = [OptionsSingleton singleObj];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PickFromTable"]){

         TableViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
-(void)done{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

    NSLog (@"Back in ViewControllerThatCallsTableViewController, Row picked is %i",optionsSingle.gblGamePicked);
   }
```

The segue identifier was entered on the storyboard by clicking on the segue and naming it in the properties inspector. The done method will be called by the TableViewController when it closes. All it says here is the row value, to prove that the original viewcontroller knows the row. Your code will take it from there.(You could pass the data in the row if you want...you'd have to declare the appropriate globalvariables for that.)

The TableViewController files have this stuff in them:

```
//  TableViewController.h


@protocol ViewControllerThatCallsTheTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) done;
@end

@interface TableViewController
```

The protocol tells TableViewController that the "done" method is in the original view controller, not in TableViewController itself.

```
//  TableViewController.m

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "BeginningCell.h"  // used for the prototype cell
#import "OptionsSingleton.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

      optionsSingle = [OptionsSingleton singleObj];

    //other stuff: arrays for filling the table, etc.
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

optionsSingle.gblRowPicked=indexPath.row+1;

     [self.delegate  done];

}
```

There you go...I hope I found all the code in my working program that applies to your situation. Sorry if I omitted anything.

-Rob